# POP3 email checker similar to Gmail notifier for Windows?

Tags: windows, email, pop3

Is there a free, pop3 email checker for Windows that behaves similar to Google's GMail Notifier?  Minimize to Tray, and notification, double click to launch default email client?

Comment: Doesn't your default e-mail client support this (through an add-on)?

Comment: I'm using Mail in Windows Live Essential... no, it's pretty basic.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [POP Peeper](http://www.poppeeper.com/) for a number of years and found it quite useful. The interface is somewhat dated (as is the company's website), but it works well. It supports a variety of account types, including POP, IMAP, and a variety of web-based e-mail systems (Hotmail, Yahoo, et al).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[I like Mailwasher](http://www.mailwasher.net/mailwasher-free). The free version only allows one email address but the paid pro version can have as many as needed.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I totally forgot this gem, thank you.  I think I used it like 10+ yrs ago

Comment: Its a keeper...

Comment: oh, spoke too soon.  It crashes too much on my Win 7 64-bit.

Comment: I have no problems with it on my W7 64bit, version 6.5.4 though, I refuse to upgrade, it works too good.

Answer (score 1):

[PopTray](http://www.poptray.org/) might be worth a look.

> **Main Features:**
>
> - Unlimited number of Accounts
> - Show number of messages directly on the TrayIcon (rotating by
>     account)
> - Quickly preview a message
> - Delete messages from the server without downloading them
> - Rules that identify a message according to your criteria, then does
>     one of these  - actions:
>
>   - Play different notification sound
>   - Delete from the server
>   - Run any EXE file
>   - Mark as Spam
> - etc ...
> - Configurable Hot-keys/Mouse-Buttons/Command-Line options for most
>     functions
> - Plug-in Support:
>
>   - Protocol plug-ins (e.g. IMAP4, Hotmail, Gmail, etc.)
>   - Notify plug-ins (e.g. Flashing scroll-lock light, ScreenSaver)
> - Spam management using rules and white/black lists
> - Multiple notfications (play sound, pop-up, etc)
> - Translated into 30+ languages
> - Complete Install / Uninstall

[image]